# Getting mosh work on Windows with truecolor (24bit)

Tags: windows, windows-10, colors, mosh

I'm trying to get mosh.org work on Windows with truecolor (24-bit) support. Mosh [includes truecolor support](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/commit/6cfa4aef598146cfbde7f7a4a83438c3769a2835) since [version 1.4](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/961). However:

- There is no native Windows client.  The website https://mosh.org/#getting points to using a Chrome extension.
- The extension [is no longer supported](https://github.com/rpwoodbu/mosh-chrome/issues/223) and doesn't work with recent Chrome versions.
- Instead [it's suggested](https://github.com/rpwoodbu/mosh-chrome/issues/223#issuecomment-1268422280) to use the [Ssh Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd) which now includes Mosh. But **only version 1.3.2.**

---

Then I tried to compile Mosh 1.4 from source on [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/). It compiled just fine:

```
% mosh --version
mosh 1.4.0 [build mosh-1.4.0-19-g1105d48]
```

I have `COLORTERM=truecolor` set. Truecolor support works locally within [Windows Terminal](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701), tested with https://github.com/termstandard/colors.

[image]

I also have

```
% cat ~/.ssh/config
SendEnv             COLORTERM
```

so that the variable propagates to the remote system.

When connecting via ssh, truecolor support works. But when connecting via mosh 1.4 (and also 1.3.2), truecolor still doesn't work.

[image]

Any ideas how to debug the problem further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out [the solution](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/1288#issuecomment-1675914197) is simple: The server-side mosh binary must also be of version 1.4+. With that fixed it works as expected!